# how to put list item text and list item image in same line?

Tags: html, css

HTML:-

```css
ul {
  list-style-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGSp1.png);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit, consequatur?</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit, consequatur?</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit, consequatur?</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit, consequatur?</li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to put image as bullet in list item but the issue is image and list item text is not in same line.

[screenshot of output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKL6W.png)

[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGSp1.png) (images is 16px X 16px)

Comment: can you share the full link of the image?

Comment: updated @TemaniAfif

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use it as a pseudo element and you will have better control on the position and also the size:

```css
ul {
  list-style:none;
}

li {
  position:relative;
}
li:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:2px;
  left:-20px;
  width:16px;
  height:16px;
  background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGSp1.png);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit, consequatur?</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit, consequatur?</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit, consequatur?</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit, consequatur?</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: By the way, what's the meaning of `content: "";` in `li:before`?

Comment: @GermaVinsmoke the pseudo element need to have a content because it's main purpose is to add content before or after .. so if there is no content defined the browser will not render it and since we don't have any particular content to add we simply add an empty string